# MySql join two select statements without subquery in from clause

Tags: mysql, join

How can i join this two selects without using a subquery in the from clause?

***SELECT 0 a UNION SELECT 1 a UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
    UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9;***

***SELECT 0 b UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 20 
    UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 40 UNION SELECT 50 UNION SELECT 60
     UNION SELECT 70 UNION SELECT 80 UNION SELECT 90;***

The result should be 100 Rows:

every a(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) joined with every b(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)

I need that, because i can´t create a view, if there are subqueries in the from clause...

Thank you!

Comment: use `CROSS JOIN `

Answer (score 2):

Use `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
( SELECT 0 a UNION SELECT 1 a UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
    UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) AS A


CROSS JOIN

(
 SELECT 0 b UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 20 
    UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 40 UNION SELECT 50 UNION SELECT 60
     UNION SELECT 70 UNION SELECT 80 UNION SELECT 90
) AS B
```

---

**Note:**

If table `A` has `n` rows and table `B` has `m` rows then

`A CROSS B` will have  `m * n` rows

Comment: **without using a subquery in the from clause** so i can´t create a view this way... :(

Comment: How on earth you would join these two selects if you don't treat them as tables? I am sorry if I didn't get you.